# MPI resource specific implementation

Tags: openmp, openmpi

I'm sorry to mind you all, i'd like to make a custom structure for a program using both mpi and openmp. My aim would to be have subsets of adiacent parallel cores doing multithreading and the masters communicating with mpi between the various subsystems.

The hope would be to combine the speed-ups to compensate for the mpi saturation of messages.

I know that with OPENMP i can select manually the cores i want to be used with OMP_PLACES specifying the core number. Is there any way to do the same with MPI?

I know there is mapping and rankings but as far as i've understood it is just a grouping of cores already reserved for MPI as i give the number in the execute command.

EDIT1: Using **Open MPI 1.8.4**

The need for this is that i have to use a cartesian tolopology and my problem has periodic boundaries so i happen to have messages that will congest the bandwidth

Thanks for your attention

Comment: Your question is about how an MPI implementation specifies the resources to be used. That will  be different for each implementation, so your question needs to include information about which implementation you will use. If the MPI implementation does it right, then you shouldn;t need to do anything at the OpenMP level. (Most OpenMP implementations will default to using all the logicalCPUs they have access to).

Comment: thank you for you attention, i'm using **Open MPI 1.8.4**